# django form not working when manually rendering form fields

Tags: django, django-forms

**ISSUE:** When rendering the form fields manually the form does not submit

I have a django form that I was rendering with `{{ form | crispy}}` for front end purposes I need to render the form fields manually. When rendering the fields manually the form does not submit. It works perfectly if I use the `{{ form | crispy}}`. The only change i made to the code is in the html rendering the elements manually

html

```
<div class="content-section">
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="PostForm" data-models-url="{% url 'ajax' %}" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Create Post</legend>
        
        {{ form.image | as_crispy_field}}
        <h4>heading text</h4>
        <hr class="solid">
        {{ form.title | as_crispy_field}}
        <h4>Heading text</h4>
        <hr class="solid">
        {{ form.model | as_crispy_field}}
        <h4>Heading text</h4>
        <hr class="solid">
        {{ form.manufacture | as_crispy_field}}

    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

views.py

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Post,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

forms.py

```
from crispy_forms.layout import Fieldset, Layout
from django.forms import ModelForm
from blog.models import Post, Manufactures, Models
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper



class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
       fields = 'image', 'title', 'model', 'manufacture'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['model'].queryset = Models.objects.none()
        



        if 'manufacture' in self.data:
            try:
                model_manufacture_id = int(self.data.get('manufacture'))
                self.fields['model'].queryset = Models.objects.filter(model_manufacture_id=model_manufacture_id)#.order_by('name')
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass  # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty City queryset
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['model'].queryset = self.instance.country.city_set#.order_by('name')
```

Comment: Exactly what problem you face?

Comment: When rendering the form fields manually the form does not submit.

Comment: It looks like you did not specify an `action="..."` in your form.

Comment: Render the forms errors (`{{ form.errors }}` for simplicity, but you can display the errors for individual fields and the non-field errors separately, See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually , I find that people forget to render the errors while rendering the field manually :( ) and see why the form may be invalid

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize I miss a required value on the form when displaying it was causing the error!